# Image Size for different Screen Resolutions in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, screen-resolution

I am Developing a Windows Store application. There are seven resolutions in Windows. **I want to set different image sizes for different resolutions. Can any one know what are the image sizes for Windows Simulator Resolutions.**

These are the resolutions Simulator provide:

- 10.6" 1024*768,
- 10.6" 1366*768,
- 10.6" 1920*1080,
- 10.6" 2560*1440,
- 12"    1280*800,
- 23"    1920*1080,
- 27"    2560*1440,

  **My question is Image sizes for these resolutions regarding Background Image, Launch image(splash screen).**  **I want to Select image based on Screen Size. Guide me the what are the image sizes regarding of Screen size.**
  I searched through out in internet. Help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you please list out the what are the screen sizes in Windows Store apps. Mean which resolution for Tablet, Desktop, Laptop.. etc

Answer (score 2):

Depending of the kind of application that you are dealing with, the best option may be to scale or to adjust the image size.

Take a look a this resource [Guidelines for scaling to screens (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx) it will provide a complete picture of this very important topic.

In the same reference guide you have [Guidelines for scaling to pixel density (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx)

I truly recommend to read the MSDN reference to Windows 8 apps. It's very well documented and has tons of examples.

It's worth mentioning that the system can automatically swap images for you when the screen resolution goes above 140% and 180% of 1366 x 768. To take advantage of this "auto swapping" simply include three versions of your image:

- MyImage-100.jpg
- MyImage-140.jpg
- MyImage-180.jpg

Then, when you reference the image in your application just reference it as **MyImage.jpg**. The system will take care of the rest.

If you need to swap images out at resolution thresholds other than 140% and 180% you will need to write your own custom code.

Comment: @Jared Bienz. My issue is For Microsoft store apps there are many Screen resolutions, as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj679352.aspx
What about the remaining resolutions which are higher than & lower than 1366x768...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great resources that Agustin has provided, please note that the launch image/splash screen must always be 620 x 300 pixels, regardless of your screen size/resolution.  You can find this in your Package.appxmanifest file under the "Application UI" tab, at the bottom.

Comment: Good point Jennifer. Although you may want to include different artwork in-app for different resolutions, the splash screen is fixed at one size. Set the background color of the splash screen to match the edge pixels of the image and it will give a seamless appearance.

Comment: Can you please list out the what are the screen sizes in Windows Store apps. Mean which resolution for Tablet, Desktop, Laptop.. etc

Comment: Devendra, there is no fixed resolution for tablets etc. like there is for the iPad.  I have a tablet that I run at 1366x768, but there are lots of options available for tablets, desktops, and laptops across the many devices that run Windows 8.